# Updating OmniSharp extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

My `C# for Visual Studio Code` extension is at 1.21.5. How do I update it to the latest 1.34.4?

There is a Disable button and an Uninstall button, but I can't find an option to perform an update.

The Check for Extension Updates menu button when clicked simply says "All extensions are up to date."

The extension is enabled globally, if that is of relevance.

Comment: It's possible that the latest version requires a newer VSCode version than the one you have installed.

Comment: Same here. VS Code 1.40.2, "C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)" at 1.21.8 and updater doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Omnisharp updates automatically when you start up vs code, but you could be sure and uninstall the c# extension and install it back; your problem should be gone.